# unique pointer vs raw pointer

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

Trying to understand the unique_pointer vs raw pointer access

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    int a = 10;
    int *x = &a;
    int *y = &a;
    std::unique_ptr<int> p1 = std::make_unique<int>(a);
    std::cout<<*x<<*p1<<*y<<"\n";
    // prints 101010
    *p1 = 20;
    std::cout<<*x<<*p1<<*y<<"\n";
    // prints 102010
    *x =30;
    std::cout<<*x<<*p1<<*y<<"\n";
    // 302030
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
101010
102010
302030

Program ended with exit code: 0
```

In the above code x, y,p1 are all pointing to variable a;
so change of value a should have reflected to all the pointers dereferencing .

Please do help me to understand the behaviour I am few of the guys who all are now moving from use of raw pointers to smart pointers.

Comment: `make_unique` created a new object, your pointers are not pointing to the same memory adress

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're wrong, `p1` doesn't point to `a`.

Instead `std::make_unique<int>(a)` create a brand new `int` object and initialize it to the current *value* of `a`.

---

To make `p1` point to `a` you need to do

```
std::unique_ptr<int> p1(&a);
```

However that brings with it other problems, like `p1` taking over the *ownership* of `&a`, and attempting to free that memory when `p1` is destructed (which is not possible).

You could use [the Boost `null_deleter`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/null_deleter.html) to avoid the last problem.

But I recommend that in most situation you should not look at the smart pointers a simple self-deleting pointers, but instead from an ownership perspective.

Answer (score 1):

The code below is based on MSVC.

#### Reason

- `std::make_unique()` let you make new object, not reference the parameter

  - You can find that the unique_ptr `p1` gets a different address

    ```
    int a = 10;                                         // &a = 0x000000bd7d5dfb74
    int* x = &a;                                        // x = 0x000000bd7d5dfb74
    int* y = &a;                                        // y = 0x000000bd7d5dfb74

    std::unique_ptr<int> p1 = std::make_unique<int>(a); // p1._Mypair._Myval2 = 0x00000288fbbd6ba0
    std::cout << *x << *y << *p1 << "\n";

    *p1 = 20;
    std::cout << *x << *y << *p1 << "\n";

    *x = 30;
    std::cout << *x << *y << *p1 << "\n";
    ```

[image: screenshot]

#### Solution

- As `Some programmer dude` said, use `std::unique_ptr<int> p1(&a);`

  - This results that the unique_ptr indicates the same address

    ```
    int* a = new int(10);        // a = 0x0000027411117260
    int* x = a;                  // x = 0x0000027411117260
    int* y = a;                  // y = 0x0000027411117260

    std::unique_ptr<int> p1(a);  // p1._Mypair._Myval2 = 0x0000027411117260
    std::cout << *x << *y << *p1 << "\n";

    *p1 = 20;
    std::cout << *x << *y << *p1 << "\n";

    *x = 30;
    std::cout << *x << *y << *p1 << "\n";
    ```
- FYI, as the unique_ptr `p1` will free the memory of `a`, you do not need to free the memory explicitly.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: but results into an undefined behaviour at the end, either when `p1` goes out of scope or when `a` goes out of scope

Comment: @AdamBajger Thank you for the comment. I have replaced the codes and screenshots. :)